# Alarm rescheduling - AlarmManager pendingIntent is not null after force kill

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm searching for a way to understand when an app has been somehow force killed, so that I can perform some tasks the next time the user manually opens the app (restart alarms, reschedule jobs, do cleaning etc). To achieve this I've scheduled an AlarmManager far in the future, and every time the app starts I check if the corresponding pending intent exists or not. If it exists, no force kill happened and so I do nothing. If the pending intent is null instead, it means the app was force killed and the alarm was descheduled, so I schedule it again and I execute all the needed tasks.
Unfortunately this approach isn't working: if I force kill the app from the device settings, the first time I reopen the app the pending intent is still existing (method isForceStopped() below returns false), but if i exit from the app and I open it again then the pending intent is null (isForceStopped() returns true).

This is the behavior I find:

- AlarmManager is scheduled the first time the app starts
- I force kill the application in the device settings I start the app again -> pending intent is not null (isForceStopped() returns false)
- I close the app and I start it again -> pending intent is null now (isForceStopped() returns true, alarm is rescheduled
- From now on, alarm is scheduled and pending intent is not null

Given this behavior, the user must open the app twice before I could perform the needed actions after force kill. My questions are:

- Why the pending intent still exists when the app is launched for the first time? Am I missing something in my code?
- More in general, are there better ways to achieve what I need (understand that a force kill happened)?

Current code

```
public class AlarmChecher {

private static final String ACTION_FORCE_STOP = "ACTION_FORCE_STOP";
private Context mContext;
private static final int ALARM_ID = -1;
private static final long TEN_YEARS = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(10 * 365);

public AlarmChecher(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

public boolean isForceStopped() {
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(mContext, FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pendingIntent == null) {
        setAlarmChecher(mContext);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private Intent getIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, ForceStopRunnable.BroadcastReceiver.class));
    intent.setAction(ACTION_FORCE_STOP);
    return intent;
}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, int flags) {
    Intent intent = getIntent(context);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ALARM_ID, intent, flags);
}

private void setAlarmChecher(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = getPendingIntent(context, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long triggerAt = System.currentTimeMillis() + TEN_YEARS;
    if (alarmManager != null) {
        alarmManager.setExact(RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAt, pendingIntent);

    }
}
```

}

Then in onCreate() method of my activity

```
AlarmChecher alarmChecher = new AlarmChecher(this);
if (alarmChecher.isForceStopped()) {
    //do actions
    alarmJobUtils.rescheduleAll();
}
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Got Kotlin lang?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use negative values for `ALARM_ID`. There have been many reports of strange behaviour with  negative values for the `requestCode`.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your response. I've tried to set ALARM_ID = 999999 but the behavior is the same. isForceStopped() returns false after force stop even if alarm ACTION_FORCE_STOP isn't listed using adb command "adb shell dumpsys alarm"

Comment: The alarm is not the issue. When you call `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` this doesn't check if the alarm is set. This checks if the `PendingIntent` exists. You can see the list of existing `PendingIntent`s by using `adb shell dumpsys intents`. If the `PendingIntent` exists, the call to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` will return a non-null value.

Comment: Correct. My problem is, I have no way to understand if an alarm is set (no getAlarm() let me say) so my guessing was that force-kill destroys pendingIntents too. If it doesn't (it destroys alarms but not corresponding pendingIntents) I really don't know how to check if the alarm is still scheduled and so if a force-kill happened.

Comment: Why do you need to know if the alarm is set? Why not just always assume thecapp was force stopped and perform the necessary tasks every time?

Comment: It can be done but I don't see this solution so performing. I like to execute the code only when and if it's needed. If it really cannot be done I will go through this way but to me it makes no sense if there's no way to recognize a force kill.